# Do specific items have the same effect as other similar items?

Tags: nethack

In *Nethack*, I find myself a **ruby potion**, and drinking it gives me poison. Later in the same dungeon, I find a **"Liquor Emporium"** (potion shop) and find other *ruby potions* in there as well. Do all items within the same dungeon have a constant effect (e.g. All *ruby potions* are poisonous)?

Comment: Why is "ruby potion" bolded in the first sentence and italicized in the rest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Item effects for similar descriptions will inherited *within* an ascension run, but are randomized at the start of a run. Taking your ruby potion for example. If you drink one and it poisons you then all ruby potions are poisonous **for that run**. If you die or ascend and start a new run, then the effects of a ruby potion will be randomized at the start of that run. It may be poison or may be something else.

Comment: This also applies to wands, scrolls, spellbooks, and magical equipment (e.g. if you find a visored helm that turns out to be a Helm of Opposite Alignment, *all* visored helms are HoOAs - in that game). That said, there are a few things with fixed descriptions; for example, "a clear potion" is always water, and most weapons and armour have fixed descriptions, too.

Comment: Ha. I love the gag of calling each game an 'ascension run'. I've been playing for *decades* and haven't come within a million miles of ascending.

Comment: Everyone else uses the term "ascension run" to refer only to the last stages of the game; referring to the whole game that way is... certainly unusual.

Comment: @Wooble Probably comes from the fact I play Nethack *and* Kingdom of Loathing. Most KoL players refer to any run (at any stage) as an *ascension run*.